# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments and error E0980 call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator()

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program and got a problem which I've been googling and can't solve it. The **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments**  and **Error (active) E0980 call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type** are refered to the .get_name() function in student.cpp.
Can you help me?

```
//school.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    Student paul("Paul");
    cout << paul.get_name();
}
```

```
//student.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {

public:
    string student_name;
    Student(string new_student_name);

    string get_name();

};
```

```
//student.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.hpp"
using namespace std;

Student::Student(string new_student_name) {
    student_name = new_student_name;
}

string Student::get_name()
{
    return student_name();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`student_name` is a variable of type `string`. It is not a function (nor a function-like object), so you shouldn't use `()` operator (function call operator) to that.

You should use

```
return student_name;
```

instead of

```
return student_name();
```

in the `Student::get_name` function.

Comment: Yeah, it was that! Thanks a lot!